# A foreign key constraint fails with Zend_Db_Table

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have to tables and their SQL is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
itemID INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
price FLOAT NOT NULL,
stock INTEGER NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE salesrecord (
recordID INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
itemID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
recordDate DATE NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES item (itemID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And this is my Zend_Db_Table concrete classes:

```
<?php
class Store_Model_Items extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
  protected $_name = 'item';
  protected $_rowClass = 'Store_Model_Item';
  protected $_dependTables = array('Store_Model_SalesRecords');
}


<?php
class Store_Model_SalesRecords extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
  protected $_name = 'salesrecord';
  protected $_referenceMap = array(
    'Item' => array(
        'columns' => array('itemID'),
        'refTableClass' => 'Store_Model_Items',
        'refColumns' => array('itemID'),
        'onDelete' => self::CASCADE
    )
  );
}
```

When I try to delete a row in item table,
I get this message:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`newstore/salesrecord`, CONSTRAINT `salesrecord_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`itemID`) REFERENCES `item` (`itemID`))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want delete the record from parent table, firstly you should delete related records in a child table. Also you can add ON DELETE CASCADE checking, it will help automatically delete related records in the child table. Try to recreate your FK in this way -

```
ALTER TABLE salesrecord
  DROP FOREIGN KEY salesrecord_ibfk_1; -- change FK name here!

ALTER TABLE salesrecord
  ADD CONSTRAINT salesrecord_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (itemID)
    REFERENCES item(itemID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Change 'salesrecord_ibfk_1' with actual FK name.